# solution explorer's scroll works instead of editor's

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In my Visual Studio 2010 when scroll over editor my solution explorer is scrolling instead.

Does anybody have/had this problem?  I cannot find any information in the web about this.

Comment: any luck with this problem? I've got the same annoyance

Comment: no        .............. ....

Comment: I would also like to know how to solve this issue. I've had it in the past, and got around it, but now my machine has been reformatted and I can't remember how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this issue, and found a solution which worked nicely in my machine. The reason was the mouse drivers.

http://thecurlybrace.blogspot.sg/2010/08/mouse-scroll-whell-issues-with-visual.html

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: thank you for your comment. I think it works for somebody but unfortunately not for me (I have XP)